# Obter valores de checkbox em DataTable com paginação

Tags: jquery

Possuo uma tabela com o plugin [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/).

Em cada linha de minha tabela, possuo um `<input type="checkbox" />` . Possuo um botão para ativar/desativar os itens descritos em cada linha da tabela.

Basicamente, percorro todos os `checkbox` e os envio para um outro método que ai faz certas ações relacionadas ao banco de dados, parte irrelevante da pergunta.

O meu problema começa quando uso a paginação da tabela pois ao percorrer os `checkbox`, apenas consigo obter os valores dos que estão em tela. Pelo o que notei, o [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) não da um simples `hide()` nos registros das outras páginas, ele vai montando os `tr` da `table` conforme a página atual.

Como posso proceder para independente da página, obter todos os `checkbox` selecionados?

Comment: Essa solução do bDestroy é bastante útil. Inclusive, eu resolvi meu problema utilizando essa configuração de inicialização.Só não entendi muito o serialize(), visto que só o bDestroy resolve a questão da paginação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bSort": false
});
var Check = table.$('input:checked').serialize();
```

Faço um restart no carregamento da tabela `example` para poder tratar como um objeto `DataTable`, assim com o `serialize` envio todos os dados de `input:checked`, dados os quais trato na minha camada C# via `Ajax`.

Comment: Muito bom cara, me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Minha sugestão nesse caso é usar JSF... pois tem bastante código exemplo e nele você consegue criar tabelas com facilidade.

por exemplo:

No trecho de código abaixo, você tem um `ManagedBean`, nomeado bean, e esse ManagedBean tem uma lista de objetos....

Com esse elemento `h:dataTable` você consegue nesse simples trecho de código montar uma tabela com todos os elementos da lista, utilizando os valores presentes nos atributos de cada objeto.

Detalhe: como no checkbox o value é : `#{item.checked}`, o seu objeto item deve ter um atributo `boolean checked` com seus respectivos `getters and setters`. Assim, quando marcar/desmarcar o item, seu atributo será atualizado com o novo valor. Daí, quando precisar saber se o objeto foi selecionado ou não, basta verificar esse atributo.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    <h:column>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.checked}" />
    </h:column>
    ...
</h:dataTable>
```

JSF possui vários sites com exemplos de elementos utilizados, como:
[Primefaces](http://primefaces.org/) e [Richfaces](http://richfaces.jboss.org/)

Para a construção de um ManagedBean, consulte [aqui](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_managed_beans.htm) para começar!